# Remove Tick marks in Line chart, APACHE POI

Tags: excel, apache-poi

I've generated a line chart using Apache poi. There are 400 values in the X axis and the tick marks make some values unclear as there is lot of tick marks there. Therefore, I need to remove the tick marks in X axis. Is there any way to remove them?
My code is as follows.

```
Drawing drawing = sheet4.createDrawingPatriarch();
ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 17, 22);

Chart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);
ChartLegend legend = chart.getOrCreateLegend();
legend.setPosition(LegendPosition.RIGHT);

LineChartData data = chart.getChartDataFactory().createLineChartData();

ChartAxis bottomAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createCategoryAxis(AxisPosition.BOTTOM);
ValueAxis leftAxis = chart.getChartAxisFactory().createValueAxis(AxisPosition.LEFT);
leftAxis.setCrosses(AxisCrosses.AUTO_ZERO);

ChartDataSource<Number> xs = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet1, new CellRangeAddress(1, 380, 0, 0));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys1 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet1, new CellRangeAddress(1, 380, 1, 1));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys2 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet1, new CellRangeAddress(1, 380, 3, 3));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys3 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet1, new CellRangeAddress(1, 380, 4, 4));
ChartDataSource<Number> ys4 = DataSources.fromNumericCellRange(sheet1, new CellRangeAddress(1, 380, 8, 8));

LineChartSeries series1 = data.addSeries(xs, ys1);
series1.setTitle("Value 1");
LineChartSeries series2 = data.addSeries(xs, ys2);
series2.setTitle("Value 2");
LineChartSeries series3 = data.addSeries(xs, ys3);
series3.setTitle("Value 3");
LineChartSeries series4 = data.addSeries(xs, ys4);
series4.setTitle("Value 4");

chart.plot(data, bottomAxis, leftAxis);

XSSFChart xssfChart = (XSSFChart) chart;
CTPlotArea plotArea = xssfChart.getCTChart().getPlotArea();
plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSmooth();
CTBoolean ctBool = CTBoolean.Factory.newInstance();
ctBool.setVal(false);
plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].setSmooth(ctBool);
for (CTLineSer ser : plotArea.getLineChartArray()[0].getSerArray()) {
    ser.setSmooth(ctBool);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, for me `apache poi` version `3.17` there are no tick marks per default. But my answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51530552/change-colors-of-line-chart-apache-poi should answer this question too.

Answer (score 0):

**For newer POI versions** , we could remove the marker style using:

```
series1.setMarkerStyle(MarkerStyle.NONE);
```

**Additional Info:**
In addition to that it support different marker styles:

```
MarkerStyle.CIRCLE
MarkerStyle.DASH
MarkerStyle.DIAMOND
MarkerStyle.DOT
MarkerStyle.PICTURE
MarkerStyle.PLUS
MarkerStyle.SQUARE
MarkerStyle.STAR
MarkerStyle.TRIANGLE
```

I'm using the library  version : `4.1.2`.